# Ajax call response doesn't get inserted into a “Div” tag jquery selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

Could you please tell me why I can see the response correctly in the web browser console but the response doesn't get inserted into the 'Div' tag.

The only thing that gets inserted into the "Div" tag is:

```
    [object Object] [object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Backend response example:

```
    [ { "id": 67, "avaliable": true, "date": "2020-06-16T08:00:00", }, { "id": 68, "avaliable": true, "date": "2020-06-16T09:00:00", } ]
```

Code:

```
    function myFunction(){ $.ajax({ url: '/appt/all/doc/Dr.Lee/date/2020-06-16', type: 'GET', dataType: "json", success: function (response) {

for( i = 0;i<=response.length;i++){
     console.log(response[i]);
     $("div").append("<b>"+response[i]+"</b>");
    }
}
    }); }
```

Comment: try response [i]["id"] and so on

Comment: What happens when you wrap response[i] with JSON.stringify() in your append method call? `$("div").append("<b>"+rJSON.stringify(response[i])+"</b>");`

Comment: Right, you need to either stringify your data or specifically tell it which value you would like to use

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the object to string and then insert it to the div.

```html
for( i = 0;i<=response.length;i++){
     console.log(response[i]);
     $("div").append("<b>"+JSON.stringify(response[i])+"</b>");
  }
```